# Вывод информации telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

При запуске самого кода, информация из таблицы выводится в консоль, что необходимо сделать чтобы эту информацию отправлял бот.

```
elif args[0] == "/start":           
con = MySQLdb.connect(host="host", user="host", passwd="host", db="host")
                cur = con.cursor()
                cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM vk""")
                for row in cur.fetchall():
                    print(row)
                con.close()
                bot.sendMessage(message["chat"]["id"], "")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print(row)` замените на `bot.sendMessage(message["chat"]["id"], row)`.

Вместо `message["chat"]["id"]` можете вписать нужный вам id.